# What was the motivation behind the fraction ideal's name?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, soft-question, terminology

The fraction ideal is the ideal
$$(I:J)=\{x\in R:xJ\subseteq I\}$$where $I, J$ are ideals in $R$.

My question is, why is it called a fraction ideal? (Sometimes it is called the "Ideal quotient of $I$ by $J$".) After learning about the isomorphism theorems, I kind of see why the quotient ring is called that. Correct me if I am wrong, but we are, in a way, dividing by the ideal, taking representatives from the ring.

I understand how the fraction ideal is defined, but I do not see how this fraction ideal is analogous to a fraction.

Comment: It is a fraction in the sense that $(I:J)J=I$ when $R$ is, for example, a Dedekind domain.

Comment: Doesn't $xj = i$ give you an analogy with fractions ?